# alternate row color with knitr:kable in R Markdown

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, knitr, xelatex

I want to display alternating row colors using `knitr:kable`in R Markdown rendering PDF with `xelatex`. E.g. 
`knitr::kable(mtcars,format="markdown")`

Comment: Assuming you're rendering to HTML, that's more a matter of your CSS.

Comment: This is easier with the [pixiedust](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pixiedust/index.html) package.

Comment: @Remko I just tried the examples from the website vignettes but the alternating color didn't seem to work.  I just downloaded the most recent version of `pixiedust` from CRAN.

Comment: @Remko I see the problem, I had to change `output: html_document` to `output:  rmarkdown::html_vignette` to get it to work with `pixiedust`.  That is probably in the docs somewhere.  It would be nice if it would work for types of output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`kableExtra`](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/)

```
knitr::kable(mtcars, "html") %>%
  kable_styling("striped")
```

or

```
knitr::kable(mtcars, "latex") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped")
```

Comment: how can I do this factor?

Comment: This also worked for me `knitr::kable(mtcars) %>%  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped")`

Answer (score 1):

This uses the package `kableExtra`

````
    ---
    title: "Habits"
    output: html_document
    ---
    
    <style>
    .striped tr:nth-child(even) { background: #00ff00; }
    </style>
    
    ```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
    library(kableExtra)
    
    kable(mtcars[1:15, 1:4], table.attr = "class=\"striped\"",
      format = "html")
    ```
````

This will give you an HTML output, but you can simply just "Print to PDF" from the browser

[image]